# React Hooks Error Handling Turns State To Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Hi I have created a form that uploads a file using **React Hooks**. Once the upload button is clicked the file is sent to the server using axios. So I try to also handle errors that might occur using a try/catch block. The dispatch function does not set the state when there is an error. the current state becomes a function when there is an error

Below is the link to the code at stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fe3wqk

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because the function that you pass to useReducer is returning a function instead of a state object. Try refactoring it to this:

```
function fileStatusReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "UPLOADING":
      return {
        ...state,
        uploading: !state.uploading,
        status: "Uploading..."
      };
    case "ERROR":
      return {
        ...state,
        status: action.message
      };

    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

You can read more about useReducer [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer).